# Background-position как вычисляется положение?

Tags: css

В документации написано верхний левый угол, но факту все не так просто.
Объясните простыми словами как она считает.

Comment: Получается что он зафиксировал картинку и больше не двигает, но если картинка больше элемента не понятно как он ее рассчитывает

Answer (score 4):

Именно позиционирование в процентах высчитывается следующим образом:

```
a = ширина элемента // аналогично для высоты
b = ширина картинки в background-size // по умолчанию background-size: auto auto;
c = background-position в процентах   // по умолчанию background-position: 0 0;

px = (a - b) / 100 * c;
```

Визуальный пример:

```js
let bx = 200,
    by = 100,
    bs = 20;

bx = bx - bs;
by = by - bs;

$('input').on('mousemove change', function(){
  let x = $('.-x input').val(),
      y = $('.-y input').val();
  $('.block').css('background-position', `${x}% ${y}%`);
  $('.-x label').text(x+'%');
  $('.-y label').text(y+'%');
  
  $('.log').html('left: '+bx+'px - '+x+'% = '+(Math.ceil(((bx/100*x))*100)/100)+'px<br>top: '+by+'px - '+y+'% = '+(Math.ceil(((by/100*y).toFixed(2))*100)/100)+'px');
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd url('https://i.imgur.com/ps8ltR5.png') no-repeat 0% 0 / 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block::before,
.block::after {
  display: block;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #f00;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.block::before {
  content: '200px';
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.block::after {
  content: '100px';
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
}

.change {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.change input {
  width: 100%;
}

.change label {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}

.change.-x {
  width: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 5px;
}

.change.-y {
  width: 100px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: 185px;
  top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="change -x">
    <input type="range" min="0" value="0" max="100" step="1">
    <label>0%</label>
  </div>
  <div class="change -y">
    <input type="range" min="0" value="0" max="100" step="1">
    <label>0%</label>
  </div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="log"></div>
```

Comment: во чё карантин делает :))

Comment: Ну, вот и отпала надобность выкладывать подробное объяснение с нюансами. Поеду лучше на велосипеде за город. Мяска пожую на природе.

Comment: @UModeL у вас нету карантина ?

Comment: @MaximLensky : У нас просто не маньячат власти. Ну и мы не наглеем.

Comment: @UModeL у нас спецназ на улицах стоит - армейцы и менты - а 19 вообще сказали не выходить на улицу не в магазин не в в аптеку ни куда

Comment: @UModeL и ещё у меня до озера 600 метров а ходить туда нельзя ..20мрп

Comment: @MaximLensky : я интересовался дня три назад непосредственно у полисменов по поводу запретов. Сказали, что приказов нет, но по инструкции компашки более 3-х рассеивать надобно. К велосипедистам претензий нет - пока они в седле, они типа в машине и ни с кем не контактируют))

Comment: @UModeL, не, хочу увидеть ваш ответ) Уверен, код будет отличаться, скилл подтянуть всегда хорошо)

Comment: @UModeL у нас вроде любое передвижение запрещено но машины катаются но автобусы ходят по рассписанию 6-10 16-20 а раньше ездили целый день -

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 : там не столько кода, сколько букв. Экрана на полтора. Но буквы - это неинтересно. Будет время и желание, может допиши и опубликую. Но, это не точно.